# Output minimized tags from XSL transform using XSLT 2.0

Tags: xslt, xhtml, xslt-2.0, saxon

I'm transforming an XML document with mimimized `br` tags like this:

```
<br/>
```

I'm using Saxon 9, and outputting as XHTML

```
<xsl:output method="xhtml" indent="yes" use-character-maps="html-chars"/>
```

I was under the impression from the docs that when using XSLT the serializer must use minimised tag endings (if the tag body is empty, which it is), however I always get this in my output:

```
<br></br>
```

Any clues as to why this should be the case, and how I can force it to output in minimized form:

```
<br/>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output method `xhtml` will output any empty XHTML elements in the minimized way, meaning any elements like `br` that are in the XHTML namespace `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`. So without seeing more details I would guess that you have `br` result elements that are in no namespace or a different namespace. In that case the output method does not require any minimized syntax.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I will check the namespacing

Comment: You were right Martin, it was a name-spacing issue. I followed another of your answers to fix it!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408504/xslt-transformation-to-produce-valid-xhtml-a-namespace-issue